# Lossless stream of MJPEG over HTTP using several JPEG files

Tags: python, ffmpeg, vlc, mjpeg

I have `n` jpeg files which I need to stream them over HTTP to get a reasonable benchmark test on my Optical Flow algorithm. The stream must be 30fps with each images shown for exactly 1 second. So I need image number 1 to be streamed 30 times (frames?), and so on. Would it be easier to first make a video of these jpeg files then stream that video using VLC or something?

An important requirement is that the frames fetched from the stream must  be exactly same as the jpeg files.

Any solution using scripting languages (python maybe) or encoding decoding tools like `ffmpeg` or `vlc` is welcome.

Comment: Why the same image need to be streamed 30 times? Do you mean you are trying to simulate a 30fps video?

Comment: @Sraw Yes, my algorithm needs to determine that say first 30 frames are same, and frame 31 has changed.